# How to execute it correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list1 = ['192,3.2', '123,54.2']

yx = ([float(i) for i in list1])

print(list1)
```

This is the code I have and I am trying to learn for future reference on how to remove , within a list of string. I tried various things like mapping but the mapping would not work due to the comma within the num.

Comment: Please edit your question heading. Your question should reflect your goal.

Comment: You are setting `yx` to a generator expression and print the original list ... why? Your "floats" are ill formatted - what is your correct decimal divider - `.` or `,` ?  is the other one supposed to be a "thousands"-divider? or just bad text? voting to close as unclear.

Comment: The . is the decimal places but the , is what I having trouble making the list to become a float. I am just curious to know if there is a way to remove the , from the string within the list.

Comment: If you just replace the "." in what Rakesh wrote with "" it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do regex to remove the non-digits to get rid of other characters

```
import regex as re
print([float(re.sub("[^0-9|.]", "", s)) for s in list1])
```

without regex:

```
[float(s.replace(',','')) for s in list1 ]
```

output:

```
[1923.2, 12354.2]
```

Comment: But that is working with a downloaded modules. Is it possible to do it without a downloaded modules or import?

Comment: I have included the non-regex option also

Comment: Yes this work, thanks for the help. I learned something new too from asking this question.

Comment: Glad it helped! can you accept the answer either this one or other, whichever one is useful for you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove commas from a string use :

```
list1 = string.split(",")
```

the **string** variable contains your string input, you get your output in the form a list, join the list if you want the original string without the commas.

```
string_joined = "".join(list1)
```

**string_joined** will contain your string without the commas.

---

If you want your string to just remove the comma and retain the empty space at that position, your syntax :

```
string = string.replace(","," ")
```

Also, the fist two syntax I explained, can be shortened to a single syntax :

```
string = string.replace(",","")
```

---

Now if you want to iterate in your list of strings, consider each element(string) in your list one at a time :

```
for string in list1 :
    <your codes go here>
```

---

Hope this answers what you are looking for.